# Set image inside x,y image

Tags: android, image, canvas, imageview

Its possible to set any image inside other image in the pixel coordenates what i want?

First image is a big image, and the second image is a sign of a user.

I think witch canvas this is posible but i am not sure.

Anyone have a example of this?

Comment: Where you want to set second image? Bottom, top, center......

Comment: In a pixel coordenates inside the first image, for example (100,22);

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358460/how-to-copy-a-smaller-bitmap-into-a-larger-one

Comment: @AleksG He dont want to copy, instead he want to set image inside other image.

Comment: @Paresh And what is the difference? You have a large bitmap and you copy the small one onto it starting from a particular point

Comment: do you want to place the second image when you click the first image ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FrameLayout`, make big image to be the background and the little one to be on the foreground. You can change its gravity using the `android:layout_gravity` attribute. `FrameLayout` documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not going to let you set the little image at a specific x/y position.

Comment: @neilmw, Actually it will, but that's not a good idea in terms of supporting multiple screens. Always better off going with gravity.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the first image the content of a class that extends from ImageView. Then in this class, override onDraw(Canvas canvas), drawing the second the image as a Bitmap at the coordinates you specify.

E.g.

```
public class DoubleImage extends ImageView
{
    private Bitmap mSecondBitmap;
    public DoubleImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
         super(context, attrs);

         // load the second image into mSecondBitmap
         mSecondBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context, R.drawable.my_second_image);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mSecondImage, x, y, null);
    }
}
```